# Declare a Public Variant as constant

Tags: excel, vba, constants, global-object

I am having trouble assigning a value to constant variant declaration. So the declaration is this

```
Option Explicit
public const Abc as variant = ?
```

Abc is a Microfocus rumba object which gets initiated when the workbook is open, something like this

```
sub workbook_open()
   Set Abc= session.GetRDEObject()
End sub
```

But I cannot use this to assign it to the const variable, it says "Circular dependencies". The reason I am wanting to assign value is to ensure the object Abc is alive even after user executes End statement. Is there a way I can do this?.

I have tried creating a separate function and adding its return value to the Abc, but it does not work.

Comment: You could just make a `GetAbc()` function that returns that object without the need for a `Const`. (Or try using `Object` instead of `Variant`)

Comment: The value of a `Const` needs to be knowable at *compile time* (ie. before the code is actually run)

Comment: @TimWilliams, yea I agree and I think that is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

A *constant* is exactly that, so try something like this:

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Abc As Object

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Set Abc = Session.GetRDEObject()
End sub

Public Function GetAbc() As Object
    Set GetAbc = Abc
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. But if the I make the Abc as private, user is not able to edit the object(or process data), it gives out an error "Object Required". My main goal is to keep the Abc object active after user clicks End. Please share if you have any tips.

Comment: If the user clicks End after an error message, everything is lost - that's why it is labelled _End_. To prevent that, apply _error handling_.